# Collapse 2nd navbar links to 1st navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have two navbars(not sure if two needed)...the top navbar contains logo and shopping cart link and lower navbar contains links.  On collapse, I want the lower navbar to collapse into the top navbar, so that only top navbar remains with hamburger(links) positioned on the left side, logo in center and shopping cart on right.

Code below not working.  On collapse, the 2nd navbar disappears, the shopping cart goes to left side and no collapse hamburger. Thank you in advance for assistance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Collapse</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1   /css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.second-navbar{
top:50px;
text-align:center;
border-bottom-width:2px;
z-index:1000;
height: 40px; 
}

.second-container{
padding-left:0px;
padding-right:0px;
}
.navbar-brand {
transform: translateX(-50%);
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
}
.navbar .navbar-nav {
display: inline-block;
float: none;
vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li>
        <a href='#' class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" style="font-size:24px;z-index:150;position:relative;float:right;"></a>
     </li>
   </ul>

<div class="navbar navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" style="float:left;">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
  </button>
  
</div>
</div>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top second-navbar">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#link1">LINK1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#link2">LINK2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#link3">LINK3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#link4">LINK4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>  
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using two navbars, you can use one navbar and push the `navbar-collapse`  to its own row by making the section with the shopping cart and logo full width.

To get the toggle button on the left and the shopping cart on the right, you can use `pull-left` and `-right`.

```css
.navbar-center {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header" style="width: 100%;">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" style="margin-left: 1rem">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand navbar-center" href="#">LOGO</a>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand pull-right" style="font-size:24px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart""></span><span class=" sr-only">Shopping cart</span></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

To get the logo in the middle, I added a special class.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.